# Using JSF and Spring MVC at the same time

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf

Is it possible to use Spring MVC and JSF in the one web app? We have a legacy JSF app but want to offer some functionality in Spring MVC. (Example admin section in JSF but client facing in Spring MVC). I was thinking that if you use JSF for xhtml files and Spring MVC for html files this would be possible?

Comment: refer this document  https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/spring-faces.html

Comment: It is not possible to use these two independent MVC frameworks together. Use Spring as a platform instead.

Comment: @Tiny well according Tejal you're wrong.

Comment: There is no doubt that JSF can be used on top of Spring and it is the whole thing described in that link but there is no Spring MVC at all as JSF itself is an MVC framework and integration of two similar things is impractical. It is a completely different thing (Spring != Spring MVC).